# Should you spread credit utilization across multiple cards to improve FICO score?

Tags: united-states, fico-score

Just wondering whether I should apply for a credit limit increase, or a new card that I'll never use. I have one card with good rewards that I use regularly, always pay in full and only spend what I have in the bank. But I hear credit utilization affects FICO scores, and I sometimes break 50 percent of the credit limit.

So I'm wondering, can I apply for a different card and not use it to bring the utilization factors down, or is a high utilization on one card still a red flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either ask for higher limit on the existing card, or get a new card that you many not use. The utilization is on the combined limit and combined spend.

It makes sense though for other purpose to have another card [typically if existing one is Visa the other one can be Master]. This would help in;

- If one card the lost, the exposure is not much. Plus you have other card to use in the time being.
- If one of the networks [visa/Master] is facing issue, the other one helps, though this is not often.
- There are different deals that Master & Visa have with Merchants.